# Django- Template Tag Approach

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm trying to figure out a way to print out a heading of a category if the specific category exists.  The issue I have is since Im running through my articles via for loops, I cant just post the heading if the category exists, otherwise it will print out that heading multiple times. For example this:

```
{% for x in todays_articles %}
 {% with x.categories.all as categories %}
 {% for category in categories %}
  {% if category.title == "nfl" %}
  <p><H1>NFL:
   <p>{{x.title}} {{category}}
  {% endif %}
  {% if category.title == "nba" %}
   <p>{{x.title}} {{category}}
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

will print out NFL/NBA multiple times.  I could just copy and paste it multiple times.

```
<P>NFL: 

{% for x in todays_articles %}
 {% with x.categories.all as categories %}
 {% for category in categories %}
  {% if category.title == "nfl" %}
  <p>{{x.title}} {{category}}
```

and do that for every category.  Im just wondering if there is a smarter approach to this.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you loop first for categories and then for articles?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're doing here, but I think you want the [`{% ifchanged %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using table tag and then print result of NFL and NBA in two different columns. I can elaborate further if you need!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you seem to have a section of code you need to repeat multiple times in your template.

For that you can use a template [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

However if your items are sorted by category already, you may want to simply use the `ifchanged` tag as Daniel Roseman pointed out.  If your items are not sorted by category, you may want to split these items in your view code or via separate database queries and inject them as separate variables into your template.